# Background scripts on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, bash, scripts, ssh, background-process

I have a .sh script that runs an import of more than 6 thousand **big** SQL files. 
I'm connecting to my Ubuntu server via ssh.
I want to start the script and close the connection for example. But in this case, the script stops. 
I've read about `nohup` and `disown`, but I would want to check the progress of the script every once in a while.

What would be the optimal solution in your opinion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a shell script in background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88091/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-background)

Comment: Use the above solution, and redirect the script output to a file, so you can check ..